# How do I stack a wide Polars DataFrame in Rust into a narrow DataFrame?

Tags: r, dataframe, rust, rust-polars

In R, I am stacking a data.frame like so: `stack(preds[1:(ncol(preds)-4)])`

This selects 1,000 columns, and stacks them all into a single column, while creating a second column which is a string, the name of the column that row originally came from.

I then combine the remaining columns I did not stack with cbind(), which are implicitly repeated since they do not have the same length as the stacked data.frame.

```
cbind(preds[ncol(preds)], preds[ncol(preds)-3], preds[ncol(preds)-2], preds[ncol(preds)-1], stack(preds[1:(ncol(preds)-4)]))
```

I am trying to replicate this in Rust using Polars, but cannot find any kind of stacking function. Do I just need to iterate over all the `Series` to be stacked, calling append(), and manually repeat the remaining columns and join those to the stacked one with `with_columns()`?

Comment: Sounds to me like the whole pivot / unpivot / melt complex of functionality so I'd explore the docs along those lines.

Comment: https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/frame/struct.DataFrame.html#example-1

Comment: @cadolphs Thank you, I was not familiar with this terminology, but it looks like what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`melt()` is the built-in function for this purpose. Note that the current latest release, 0.27.2, is O(n^2). If you need it to be fast you will need to install from the master branch `polars = { git = "https://github.com/pola-rs/polars" }` to get the latest bug fix that makes it O(n).